# "Can't create process." Borland C++ 97

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I'm a student learning under the C++ curriculum and am forced to work upon Borland C++ 5.02.

I have been trying to compile my code, but every time I run, or debug it it pops up a message saying 'Can't create process'. I tried to run programs using files, class, dynamic allocation and all of them pop up the same message. I checked my paths and they seem to be fine. I'm posting the code of one of the programs I tested and tried to run.

```
 # include <iostream.h>
    # include <conio.h>
    void main()
    {
    enum{a,b,c,d};
    cout << a << endl << b << endl << c << endl << d ;
    getch();
    }
```

Its a 16 bit compiler running on an emulator on a 64 bit Windows 8.1 OS.

I have read the answers to the questions that are similar to mine but none of the methods have worked for me.

This is the error it shows :-

```
Info :helloworld.cpp: out of date with destination helloworld.obj
Info :  helloworld.cpp: source date 11:22:18 23/03/2015  destination date <unknown>
Info :Compiling C:\Users\prana_000\Desktop\All computer related guides and projects\C++ works\12th grade\helloworld.cpp
Info :Linking C:\Users\prana_000\Desktop\All computer related guides and projects\C++ works\12th grade\helloworld.exe
```

Comment: It's `int main` not `void`. Also just out of interest, why are you using a 18 year old compiler?

Comment: @zenith Yea, i get that a lot from everywhere , but we're forced to use only void main in our exams , kind of a standard. Plus , my programs all seemed to be working fine for the past 2 years with void main , so i dont think that should be the issue . Our syllabus forces us to use either Turbo C++ or Borland C++ 5.02 , and i think our school made the better choice by picking Borland C++ , though 18 years old :/

Comment: @ArunA.S Im still not the luckiest , some schools even pick to teach Python , which i'd consider is the cream of the three

Comment: Nobody thinks `void main` is the reason for your error. It's still wrong though. What is the error verbatim? Don't ever ever paraphrase error messages.  What has changed that means you can no longer run your programs? Does it matter where the executable is saved?

Comment: How are you running Borland C++? What host environment are you using?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Nothing has changed as far as i remember . The file im saving my programs in has been the same , and ive ben careful not to tamper with the compiler at all , this error has just popped up unexpectedly . Plus , it also mentions that the  compiler is 'out of date with the filename.obj'.

Comment: @Dai Im guessing you mean my operating system? Its windows 8.1

Comment: Honestly, I would install a VM with Windows XP and install your tools there. Windows 8.1 looks pretty new for an 18 years old compiler.

Comment: What is the error? Please report it verbatim. Please do not paraphrase. Please try executing the program from a very different directory. On a different machine.

Comment: Is your system 64 bit? In which case you must be running a 16 or 32 bit emulator to host the 16 bit compiler? I assume it's a 16 bit compiler. There seems to be confusion over the version. 97 or 5.02.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried running a Hello World Program and this is the verbatim :- Info :helloworld.cpp: out of date with destination helloworld.obj
Info :  helloworld.cpp: source date 11:22:18 23/03/2015  destination date <unknown>
Info :Compiling C:\Users\prana_000\Desktop\All computer related guides and projects\C++ works\12th grade\helloworld.cpp
Info :Linking C:\Users\prana_000\Desktop\All computer related guides and projects\C++ works\12th grade\helloworld.exe     . Yes my system is 64 bit but as i mentioned the compiler (16 bit) has given me no trouble for 2 years.

Comment: That information should be moved to the question. Please edit. Clearly something has changed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have tried executing it from a different directory and it shows the same message. The version is 5.02 .

Comment: @pranavnairtech x64 editions of Windows cannot run 16-bit executables, no exceptions. When you say you've been fine for the past 2 years, was that on a 64-bit OS or on another OS?

Comment: @Dai Its been on the same 64 bit Windows 8 OS . It has updated to 8.1 only previous month and has worked fine uptill now.

Comment: @pranavnairtech try to move the project files to a directory path that does not contain spaces. BC5.02 originates before long file names were introduced in Windows and does not properly support them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , ive found a solution , and its , quite ironically , Turbo C++. Well its not a solution as such but i downloaded Turbo C++ 4.0 off DOSBOX and am using that as my primary compiler an everything's just fine :) . Thanks for all the help !